# Deadlocking with Java Sockets, Locks and Threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

I have two Android devices which I connect over WiFi Direct using the OS's P2P Manager. When a device connects, I launch an AsyncTask to establish a socket connection between the two devices. Once the socket is up and running (group owner has server socket and non-group owner has client socket) I want to exchange arrays of floats between the two devices as fast as possible and measure the time taken to get an estimate of bandwidth.

I do this by having each device create a `SendThread` and a `RecvThread` as soon as the socket is established with these threads responsible for the `OutputStream` and `InputStream` respectively for that device. They immediately wait on locks and I have a `TestThread` which wakes them in the correct order to do their part of the communication. i.e. `TestThread` wakes `SendThread` which wakes `RecvThread` which then wakes `TestThread` again and so one to enforce an order of execution.

Although this approach appears to work for a few seconds (I have a UI which shows the data streams), the process eventually stutters and grinds to a halt with both devices blocking on their recv threads waiting for data on the input stream.

Things I've tried:
1. Using `ObjectStream` to send a container of floats as well as `DataStream` to send floats individually.
2. Using `AsyncTask` on a thread pool executor to do the exchange instead of threads.

Both the above produced the same deadlocking result after a few seconds of smooth exchange.

My question is how can a deadlock occur in this situation? I am using buffered streams and call `flush()` before I put `SendThread` to sleep. Does sleeping the send thread somehow prevent the buffered data from being sent? It seems as though both devices and have sent but neither receive the others data. If I leave the devices for 5 minutes or so the frozen calls to `readFloat()` finally completed but then it hangs again on the next exchange.

This must be a common operation for P2P multiplayer games where you need bidrectional, continuous communication.

Code as follows is here, note that `socketSet` just encapsulates the socket (either server or client depending on the device running the code) and its streams.

Test Thread:

```
public void run()
{
    while (runFlag)
    {
        // Start timer
        long timeStart = System.nanoTime();

        // Create containers
        DataContainer containerArraySend = new DataContainer(10);
        DataContainer containerArrayRecv = new DataContainer(10);

        // Send and receive with other device //

        // Create a new latch
        workCounter = new CountDownLatch(containerArraySend.size());

        // Set the containers for the respective manager threads
        socketSet.sendThread.setDataContainer(containerArraySend);
        socketSet.recvThread.setDataContainer(containerArrayRecv);

        // Set the new latch
        socketSet.recvThread.setLatch(workCounter);

        synchronized (socketSets.lockB)
        {
            // Wake the send thread to start the exchange
            socketSets.lockB.notifyAll();
        }   

        // Wait until all the exchanges are complete and woken by recv thread
        workCounter.await();

        // Log time taken
        timeTaken = (double)(System.nanoTime() - timeStart) / 1000000.0;

    }
}
```

Send Thread:

```
// Send thread
public void run()
{
    // Call parent method to set the run flag
    super.run();

    // Immediately wait on thread creation until test thread releases it
    synchronized (socketSet.lockB)
    {
        socketSet.lockB.wait();
    }

    // Once released starts executing here
    while (runFlag)
    {
        // Writes to stream and immediate returns (non-blocking)
        for (int i = 0; i < dataContainer.size; i++)
        {
            socketSet.sendStream.writeFloat(dataContainer.dataBuffer[i]);
        }
        socketSet.sendStream.flush();

        synchronized (socketSet.lockC)
        {
            // Wake recv thread
            socketSet.lockC.notifyAll();
        }

        synchronized (socketSet.lockB)
        {
            // Sleep send thread until woken by test thread
            socketSet.lockB.wait();
        }
    }
}
```

Recv Thread:

```
// Recv thread
public void run()
{
    // Immediately lock on thread creation until send thread releases it
    synchronized (socketSet.lockC)
    {
        socketSet.lockC.wait();
    }

    // Once released starts executing here
    while (runFlag)
    {
        // Blocks until there is data to receive on the stream
        for (int i = 0; i < dataContainer.size; i++)
        {
            dataContainer.dataBuffer[i] = socketSet.recvStream.readFloat();
        }

        // Count down latch once recv complete (will wake test thread)
        latch.countDown();

        synchronized (socketSet.lockC)
        {
            // Recv thread sleeping until woken by send thread
            socketSet.lockC.wait();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would not care about that overhead. On the server you have to synchronise write access to one array strill. And i think that your locking up issue is gone then. But who am i to say so? You could try if you are desperate.

Comment: Ok, I will give it a go. Thank you for your patience and your suggestions. I have simplified the question a bit to help anyone else who wants to give it a go.

Comment: 'When a device connects, I launch an AsyncTask to establish a socket connection between the two devices' is completely pointless. You already have a connection, by definition.

Comment: @EJP you still have to setup a socket even after the Android WifiP2PManager reports a connection. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41053544/peer-to-peer-data-sharing-using-wi-fi-direct/41063269#41063269 so it is not pointless but necessary. Unless of course, you what to suggest an alternative?